Sound output isn't working on ASUS ROG Strix G18 G814JIR (2024)
I recently have purchased ASUS ROG Strix G18 G814JIR (2024). Received laptop with already installed Windows. Checked laptop performance on Windows, all component were working well, sound output also. I decided to setup dual boot (Windows and Ubuntu). Installed Ubuntu  without any problems. After some zoom meetings and sound based tools experienced that sound output isn't working, but input is working perfectly.

Tried to connect wired headphones, still no sound, but works well with Bluetooth.
Also tried to fix this through pavucontrol. I have wide range of audio types, but no one works.
List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices:
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC294 Analog [ALC294 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

My system info:

Please, let me know if there are any possible solutions of this problem.

This question is similar to: Suspend isn't working on ASUS ROG Strix G18 G814JIR (2024). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
